# Send an extra parameter through p:ajax with PrimeFaces 3.3.1 (JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

is there any way to send extra parameters with p:ajax?

I got this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="crit">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one..." itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{cat.desc}" itemValue="#{cat.id}" value="#{CatBean.cats}" var="cat" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{ConsBean.proccesCatSelection}" process="crit" update=":list,:crits" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I need to send an ID with the event "change" but it seems to send only an AjaxBehaviorEvent.

Thanks a lot for the attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the ID in an `InputHidden` and then use this :

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{ConsBean.proccesCatSelection}" 
process="crit inputHiddenId" update=":list,:crits" />
```

Then `p:ajax` will send the InputHidden content to server too.

Comment: But how do I get this InputHidden in my Bean? PS.: I can't bind it because I'll have dynamic selects.

Comment: use `onchange` event in `p:selectOneMenu` and call a javascript function and fill the input hidden with selected value. there might be other solutions but currently this comes to my mind ;)